# Unable to Login to Admin Panel in Django using Custom User Model

Tags: python, django

I have created a custom user model that overrides the default AUTH_MODEL in settings.py. I am unable to login on the admin panel using `python manage.py createsuperuser`. The message that the admin throws back at me is:

> Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

Below is my code for `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, phone, password=None):
        if not email:
            return ValueError("User must have an email address!")
        if not username:
            return ValueError("User must have a username!")
        if not first_name:
            return ValueError("User must have a first name!")
        if not last_name:
            return ValueError("User must have a last name!")
        if not phone:
            return ValueError("User must have a phone number!")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
        )
        hashed_password = make_password(password)
        user.set_password(hashed_password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, phone, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False, max_length=13)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone']

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

The methods that I have tried:

1. I have tried adding the `def is_staff()` to return that admin is a staff.
2. I'm not sure if this has an effect, but I hashed the password using the `make_password` because without it, the passwords that are stored in the database are raw.

Comment: I use `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `AUTH_MODEL`, it works for me nicely. I also use `AbstractUser` model instead of `AbstractBaseUser`, it also works as expected. You can try it. Rather than making a full `User` model, just inherit  `AbstractUser`  to your `User` model and add additional fields or override the existing one. This will remove complexity from your code and also shows no error (I hope so).

Comment: I replaced the `AbstractBaseUser` with `AbstractUser`. I also added the `        user.is_superuser = True` under the `def create_superuser()`, but still error persists. The data on the database showed that both admin and superuser are true.

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, phone, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        phone=phone,
        password=password,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Add is_staff=True and is_admin=True in:

```
user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was resolved by replacing the following piece of code

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, phone, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Replace this by

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, phone, password):
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username=username,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                phone=phone,
                password=password,)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

That should do the work.

**My Opinion**
And generally we don't require fields like first_name, phone etc.. for superusers, so you can simply not include them (incase you don't want those fields for a superuser). But for that you have to remove first_name,last_name,phone from `REQUIRED_FIELDS`

so if you want to create a superuser that requires only username,email and password, you can use the below piece of code

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user
```

**NOTE**: Removing the first_name,last_name, phone will not affect the `create_user` since you have already included the validation for requirement of those fields like

```
if not phone:
            return ValueError("User must have a phone number!")
```